# Get the selected value from collection_select rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selection

I have a collection_select in my form as:

```
<%= rf.collection_select :u_org, Org.all, :id, :name %>
```

I want the selected value from this form helper so that i can populate another collection_select based on this selection like:

```
<% @org = Org.find_by_id(##the selected id##) %>
```

so that this is populated:

```
<%= rf.collection_select :depart, @org.departments, :id, :department_name %>
```

I have tried it with

```
<% @org = Org.first %>
```

and it works perfectly fine. Please help.

Comment: if the second select is in the same form, you will have to use javascript. $('#other_select').val($('#first_select').selected())

Comment: Can you please elaborate?